# Can GSON make my JSON like a HashMap?

Tags: java, json, parsing, gson

I have a JSON String which is an array of name/value pairs like the below..

```
 String faves =   [{"name":"song","value":"Demons"},{"name":"team","value":"Yankees"}]
```

I want to read this into my Java program using GSON. Rather than creating a custom object with 2 fields (name,value), is it possible to read this like a HasMap, something like..

```
String favSong = GSON.fromJson("song");
```

I just need the easiest way to read in a value for a given name.

Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

I think this is what you are looking for:

```
Gson gson = new Gson();

Type type = new TypeToken<Map<String, String>>(){}.getType();
Map<String, String> myMap = gson.fromJson(faves, type);
```

Comment: This is a good suggestion, but I just found out that the server where the code runs is on an older version of Java which doesn't support generics. Is it possible without using generics?